# Find and then ask to perform action

Tags: vim, macros

I have a few macros to help refactor code that I have inherited. For instance, this macro adds spaces around a `=` character:

```
nnoremap <leader>bg /[^ ]=[^ ]<Return>a <Esc>la <Esc>
```

Therefore it turns this:

```
$some=thing();
```

Into this:

```
$some = thing();
```

However, in some places I prefer to leave the `=` without spaces:

```
<td class="foobar">
```

How might I separate the "search for" and then "perform" actions so that I could press `<leader>bg` to be taken to the next instance of the problematic code, and then press `j` to skip or `k` to perform the action?

I tried writing a function but I don't see how to get a single-character input in the function after having performed an action (moved the cursor to the next problematic occurrence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a single search/replace with confirmation?

```
:%s/\([^ ]\)=\([^ ]\)/\1 = \2/c
```

that you can use in a mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>bg :%s/\([^ ]\)=\([^ ]\)/\1 = \2/c
```

Comment: Thank you Romain! This doesn't scale to the use of other more complex changes, but when I get to those I'll ask a more specific question.